# Does Jupyter Notebook provide any convenient keyboard shortcut to comment or uncomment multiple lines of code at once?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Mac. I'd like to know how to quickly comment multiple lines of Python code in Jupyter Notebook. Does Jupyter Notebook provide any convenient keyboard shortcut for it?

Comment: First search hit: https://cheatography.com/weidadeyue/cheat-sheets/jupyter-notebook/